# HTML5 2 Audio tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have two audio tags in these markup. my problem is that the second one won't play

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="post-container">
        <legend>
            <strong>Zedd - Spectrum</legend>
        </h4>
        <div class="art-item">
            <img src="uploads/arts/default.jpg">
        </div>
        <audio class="audio-player" src="uploads/tracks/02 So Far.mp3"></audio>
        <div class="playerContainer">
            <ul id="playerControls">
                <li class="play-bt"></li>
                <li class="pause-bt"></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="progressContainer">
                        <!-- Progess bars container //-->
                        <div class="progressbar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="timecode">0:00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="post-container">
        <legend>
            <strong>Zedd - Spectrum</legend>
        </h4>
        <div class="art-item">
            <img src="uploads/arts/default.jpg">
        </div>
        <audio class="audio-player" src="uploads/tracks/track3.mp3"></audio>
        <div class="playerContainer">
            <ul id="playerControls">
                <li class="play-bt"></li>
                <li class="pause-bt"></li>
                <li>
                    <div class="progressContainer">
                        <!-- Progess bars container //-->
                        <div class="progressbar"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <span class="timecode">0:00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the script that plays the track

```
$(".play-bt").click(function(){
                    var $artItem = $(this).parent(".art-item");
                    console.log($artItem);
                    $artItem.find('audio').play();
                    $artItem.find(".message").text("Music started");
                });
```

My problem is that I can only play the first audio tag. what can I do to play the second tag or 3rd audio tag if there's more? the counter is the one that is selecting what audio tags to play. but as of now I have no idea how would I make the second audio tag or user selected audio tag if the are more audio post in this markup.

Comment: I suggest you first correct your markup. As @VDP already said, "id" attribute has to be unique per HTML document. Things will/won't work as expected if that's not the case.

Comment: I updated my markup. should edit the question? or post another one?

Comment: Is the problem in all browsers?

Comment: @Rob yup. although I know that the audio will not work on IE since the format o the audio is .mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not 100% sure that's the only issue but you use id a lot. id's should be unique on a page. Replace them by classes

And your references are wrong.

```
$("#play-bt").click(function(){
    // -> will allways try to play song indicated by counter (0)
    $(".audio-player")[counter].play(); 
    $("#message").text("Music started");
})
```

I don't think you want that? Don't you want to play the audio in the "post-container" ?

you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".play-bt").click(function(){
        var $post= $(this).parents(".post-container");
        $post.find('audio')[0].play();
        $post.find(".message").text("Music started");
    });
});
```

​

=> and changing the play-bt and message id's into classes

Comment: I finally replaced them but the second track still won't play

Comment: I updated my question. also I updated my code with your code but it gave me an error. "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'play' "

Comment: I edited my answer. I screwed up a little with the return of find being an array and the parent selector. And your markup is still screwed up. for example:  `<legend><strong>Zedd - Spectrum</legend></h4>`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why things don't work for you is because of your markup... in your code you try to obtain "parent" of the clicked "play-bt" class, yet "art-item" is **NOT** parent in your DOM structure. What probably makes you think it is, is your incorrect markup indentation...

Comment: Hehe that was my mistake actually, and yes because of the bad indentation. To easily indent right, paste code in: http://jsbeautifier.org/